# How to add a '3 weeks from today' timestamp into a script that includes a 'today' timestamp?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

My script already timestamps my column H (Call Time) whenever I make update column F (Notes):

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var timezone = "GMT-7";
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format.
  var updateColName = "Notes";
  var timeStampColName = "Call Time";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Today'); //Name of the sheet      where you want to run this script.


  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol =     updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only     timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Now I need to a future timestamp (3 weeks from now) on my column F (CB Date).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some other areas where the code could be improved a bit, but to address your specific request:

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var timezone = "GMT-7";
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format.
  var updateColName = "Notes";
  var timeStampColName = "Call Time";
  var cbDateColName = "CB Date";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Today'); //Name of the sheet      where you want to run this script.

  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol =     updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only     timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var cbcell = sheet.getRange(index, headers[0].indexOf(cbDateColName) + 1);
    var d = new Date();
    var cbd = new Date(d.getTime() + 3*7*24*60*60*1000);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(d, timezone, timestamp_format);
    var cbdate = Utilities.formatDate(cbd, timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
    cbcell.setValue(cbdate);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Your script does exactly what i want. Awesome!! I really appreciate the time you took to clarify this for me.